# In Python, how do I index a list with another list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I would like to index a list with another list like this

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Idx = [0, 3, 7]
T = L[ Idx ]
```

and T should end up being a list containing ['a', 'd', 'h'].

Is there a better way than

```
T = []
for i in Idx:
    T.append(L[i])

print T
# Gives result ['a', 'd', 'h']
```

Comment: It is really bizarre that `L[idx]` doesn't just work in base Python. Zen of python and all that. In numpy, things like this work just fine.

Comment: @eric A numpy array is vastly different from a CPython list object

Comment: @eric on the contrary: it would be really bizarre if `L[idx]` **did** do this in base Python. In fact, I can quote the Zen of Python to support that: "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules." `L[idx]` **does** "work" - it means that the *tuple* `(0, 3, 7)` will be supplied as an index, which will subsequently cause a `TypeError`. It would work fine with, say, a dict using tuples for its keys. (Slices are different, in that - in prehistoric times - they were a special syntax before there was a `slice` type.)

Comment: “Although practicality beats purity”

Answer (score 337, accepted):

```
T = [L[i] for i in Idx]
```

Comment: Is this faster than a for-loop or only shorter?

Comment: @daniel: both + recommended

Comment: A quick timing test (no pysco or anything, so make of it what you will) showed the list comprehension 2.5x faster than the loop (1000 elements, repeated 10000 times).

Comment: (using map and a lambda is even slower - to be expected, since it calls a function for each iteration)

Comment: +1 If the indexing list is arbitrary, then a list comrpehension is the way. I think though that, when possible, which seems not to be the case here, slices are even faster.

Comment: it seems there is no better way. Simple is better than complex

Answer (score 55):

If you are using numpy, you can perform extended slicing like that:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a=numpy.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
>>> Idx = [0, 3, 7]
>>> a[Idx]
array(['a', 'd', 'h'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

...and is probably much faster (if performance is enough of a concern to to bother with the numpy import)

Comment: My quick timeit test showed that using np.array is actually almost 3 times slower (including the conversion to array).

Comment: It works better if you need to convert it for array operations anyways. Too time-consuming for regular list operations.

Comment: I tried this approach, i.e. replace `list` with `np.array`, but `np.append` did not work correctly (i.e. the same results as for lists) when the elements themselves were jagged arrays.

Answer (score 14):

```
T = map(lambda i: L[i], Idx)
```

Comment: needed to be converted to list in py3k

Answer (score 11):

A functional approach:

```
a = [1,"A", 34, -123, "Hello", 12]
b = [0, 2, 5]

from operator import itemgetter

print(list(itemgetter(*b)(a)))
[1, 34, 12]
```

Comment: This won't work if `b` happens to contain just one item.

Answer (score 10):

I wasn't happy with any of these approaches, so I came up with a `Flexlist` class that allows for flexible indexing, either by integer, slice or index-list:

```
class Flexlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        if isinstance(keys, (int, slice)): return list.__getitem__(self, keys)
        return [self[k] for k in keys]
```

Which, for your example, you would use as:

```
L = Flexlist(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
Idx = [0, 3, 7]
T = L[ Idx ]

print(T)  # ['a', 'd', 'h']
```

Comment: which also demonstrates the power and flexibility of Python!

Comment: It's so easy to extend this as well for existing code. Simply call `existing_list = 
 Flexlist(existing_list)` and we have the required functionality without breaking any code

Comment: I did `self[int(k)]` instead, so that I could use `np.array`s as indices too. Otherwise, you will get an `np.int64` is not iterable error.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the `__getitem__` method combined with `map` like the following:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Idx = [0, 3, 7]
res = list(map(L.__getitem__, Idx))
print(res)
# ['a', 'd', 'h']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L= {'a':'a','d':'d', 'h':'h'}
index= ['a','d','h'] 
for keys in index:
    print(L[keys])
```

I would use a `Dict add` desired `keys` to `index`

Answer (score 1):

My problem: Find indexes of list.

```py
L = makelist() # Returns a list of different objects
La = np.array(L, dtype = object) # add dtype!
for c in chunks:
    L_ = La[c] # Since La is array, this works.
```