# Index list with another list? - Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

I'm somewhat new to python (switching from IDL), so I apologize if I'm not using the right terminology. I've tried looking for similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list), but can't seem to figure it out. I have two lists and I'm trying to create a histogram of the data where dat2 = 1. I've tried doing this multiple ways and it keeps giving me a TypeError

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = [1.1,4.2,5.3,8.6,10.0,1.2,41.4,23.2]
dat2 = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
ind = [i for i,v in enumerate(dat2) if v==1]
bins = np.arange(0,45,5)
plt.hist(data[ind],bins)
```

The error points to the hist() line and says "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list." I've tried `ind=map(int,ind)` and `ind=[int(i) for i in ind]` with no luck.

Comment: What you are trying to do is possible with NumPy arrays, so better initialize `data` and `dat2` as NumPy arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that if I'm reading the data from a text file?

Comment: NumPy provides functions like [`loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) to load data from files to NumPy arrays, if they are not good enough then you can convert your lists to NumPy arrays by calling [`array()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [ d1 for (d1, d2) in zip(data, dat2) if d2 == 1 ]
plt.hist(data)
```

This zips `data` and `dat2` together, creating a list of tuples `[ (1.1, 1), (4.2, 1) ... ]`. You can then use a list comprehension to keep only those tuples whose second element is `1`.

Finally, should the lists be long enough for memory to be an issue, you can replace `zip` with `itertools.izip`, which returns an iterator for the zipped lists, rather than constructing them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When you'r doing math, you typically use the `numpy` package's `ndarray` object, which specifically allows this kind of indexing:

```
data = np.array(data)
...
data[ind]
```