# I have two lists. I would like to make a third from the elements given in one of the lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, zip

Sorry for the confusing title!

I have two lists, say:

```
a = [30,55,76,43,27,28]
b = [0,2,3,5]
```

I want to make a `list c` that is both elements of a, i.e.

```
c = [30,76,43,28]  # -> the 0th, 2nd, 3rd, 5th elements of a
```

Should I use the `zip() function`?  Or can you use a simple `for loop`?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I index a list with another list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this through `enumerate` function.

```
>>> a = [30,55,76,43,27,28]
>>> b = [0,2,3,5]
>>> l = []
>>> for i,j in enumerate(a):
        for m in b:
            if i == m:
                l.append(j)


>>> l
[30, 76, 43, 28]
```

Through list_comprehension.

```
>>> a = [30,55,76,43,27,28]
>>> b = [0,2,3,5]
>>> [j for i,j in enumerate(a) for m in b if i == m ]
[30, 76, 43, 28]
```