# How can I do K fold cross-validation for splitting the train and test set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a set of documents and a set of labels.
Right now, I am using train_test_split to split my dataset in a 90:10 ratio. However, I wish to use Kfold cross-validation.

```
train=[]

with open("/Users/rte/Documents/Documents.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        train.append(line.strip().split())

labels=[]
with open("/Users/rte/Documents/Labels.txt") as t:
    for line in t:
        labels.append(line.strip().split())

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test= train_test_split(train, labels, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

When I try the method provided in the documentation of scikit learn: I receive an error that says:

```
kf=KFold(len(train), n_folds=3)

for train_index, test_index in kf:
     X_train, X_test = train[train_index],train[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = labels[train_index],labels[test_index]
```

## error

```
   X_train, X_test = train[train_index],train[test_index]
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

How can I perform a 10 fold cross-validation on my documents and labels?

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the Kfold cross-validation working? Have you seen the example on the [documentation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.KFold)?

Comment: Yes I have tried the example given there on my documents and label set, but I receive an error:    *X_train, X_test = train[train_index],train[test_index]
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this error:

**First way:**

Cast your data to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
[...]
train = np.array(train)
labels = np.array(labels)
```

then it should work with your current code.

**Second way:**

Use list comprehension to index the train & label list with the train_index & test_index list

```
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    X_train, X_test = [train[i] for i in train_index],[train[j] for j in test_index]
    y_train, y_test = [labels[i] for i in train_index],[labels[j] for j in test_index]
```

(For this solution also see related question [index list with another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list))