# Indices list access in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, indices

I want to bind `indices_list` and `data` like below. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list) and `numpy` may be useful. But in my case, indices is nested. How do I realize below?

```
indices_list = [
    [1,2],
    [0,2],
    [4]
]
data = [
    ['i', 'am', 'tom'],
    ['you', 'are', 'nice'],
    ['that', 'was', 'it'],
    ['yes', 'you', 'can'],
    ['no']
]

ideal: data[indices_list]
[
    [['you', 'are', 'nice'],
    ['that', 'was', 'it']],

    [['i', 'am', 'tom'],
    ['that', 'was', 'it']],

    [['no']]
]
```

### Update

I found my solution. Perhaps, that is best..

```
bind_data = []
for indices in indices_list:
    tmp = []
    for ind in indices:
        tmp.append(data[ind])
    bind_data.append(tmp)
print(bind_data)
# [[['you', 'are', 'nice'], ['that', 'was', 'it']], [['i', 'am', 'tom'], ['that', 'was', 'it']], [['no']]]
```

Comment: what about dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ [ data[j] for j in i ] for i in indices_list ]
```

Output:

```
[[['you', 'are', 'nice'], ['that', 'was', 'it']],
 [['i', 'am', 'tom'], ['that', 'was', 'it']],
 [['no']]]
```

Comment: Nice, this should be best.