# arrange items by two values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, items

I practice python recently. for a few days my script has stopped, because I'm struggling on a problem.
I want to sort the items by both values which has in common. like an chain. as you can see lower.

what I have:

```
dic= {'A': [62, 17], 'B': [59, 60], 'C': [60, 61], 'D': [57, 58], 'E': [61, 62], 'F': [58, 59]}
```

what I want:

```
dic={'A': [62, 17], 'E': [31, 62],'C': [60, 31],'B': [3, 60],'F': [58, 3],'D': [57, 58]}
```

to see clearly:

```
'A': [62, 17]

'E': [*31*, 62]

'C': [60, *31*]

'B': [3, 60]

'F': [58, 3]

'D': [57, 58]
```

there is a simple method to sort them ? if the topic already exists, 
can you send me the link. i haven't found it.
thank you in advance.
nb. in all case, I know the first and the last value of the chain (17 and 57)

Comment: You can't sort dictionaries. Dictionaries are [unordered key-value pairs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: I have NO idea what rule you're using to sort that

Comment: But this is somehow more than sorting. Why do the values of `'B'` change?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis at least half of the values change, not just `'B'`

Comment: You seem to have `'A':[62,17]` in both dicts. But in the first you have `'B':[59,60]` and in the second there is `'B':[3,60]`. This seems to have changed and I cannot work out why. I see how there is a chain in the second dict, but how does it relate to the first?

Comment: You should note that this is impossible in general (if I understand correctly what you're asking). Before anyone can provide a useful answer, you need to tell us more about these dictionaries. Is a unique sorting guaranteed? What happens if there are duplicates? This is a complex and fiddly problem; you need to tell us what assumptions we can make.

Comment: @Bilkokuya Yeah, I guess. If a dictionary contains only one element, you could _technically_ say it's sorted. But in my opinion, that's really a stretch. If a data structure is sorted, then it's elements are put in a certain order. But a data structure with one element can only be put in one particular order, therefore you can't sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Given what others have said about the order of a dictionary and violating the posters desire to have a dictionary, I return a sorted list.
I used the accepted answer at [In Python, how do I index a list with another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list)

```
d= {'A': [62, 17], 'B': [59, 60], 'C': [60, 61], 'D': [57, 58], 'E': [61, 62], 'F': [58, 59]}
myList = [max(value) for key,value in d.items()]
print(myList)
myIndex = sorted(range(len(myList)),key=lambda x:myList[x],reverse=True)
L = [(key,value) for key,value in d.items()]
[L[i] for i in myIndex]
```

Comment: `[(key,value) for key,value in d.items()]` ==> `list(d.items())`

Answer (score 0):

in fact i don't need a new dictionary. but a ordered list by the common value of the item.
it must be look like that:
list=[17,62,32,60,3,58,57]