# Is there a way to slice a list by its prime indices?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-slicing

Let

```
a = [1, 2, ... 99, 100] # numbers 1 to 100
b = [2, 3, ... 89, 97] # prime numbers under 100
```

Is there a Pythonic way to slice `a` by `b`?

i.e.

```
a[b]
```

output would be

```
[3, 4, ... 90, 98]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I index a list with another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is the numpy tag:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

result = a[b]
```

Time performance comparison:

```
import numpy as np
N=100_000

a = list(range(N))
b = list(range(1, N, 3))

c = np.array(a)
d = np.array(b)
```

**List Comprehension**

```
%timeit [a[i] for i in b]
2.31 ms ± 456 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Numpy**

```
%timeit c[d]
115 µs ± 7.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Using a simple test we can see numpy is 20x faster with an array of lenght 100_000, however this is not a fair comparison, since I am not taking into account the time to import the library and convert lists to arrays.

As a final remark, there is actually no need to convert also `b` to a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```py
result = [a[i] for i in b]
```