# slice lists which are dictionary's values

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary whose values are lists, how can slice that list based on indexes? For example:

```
a = {"x": [1,2,3,4], "y": [10,20,30,40]}
```

I have the list of indexes, called `indexes = [0,2]`.
I want to get `a = {"x": [1,3], "y": [10,30]}`. How can I do it without rebuilding the dictionary?
I know I can do it something like

```
{key: dict_name[key][indexes] for key in dict_name}
```

but I guess it might be inefficient because it re-builds the dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: These are two problems: (1) how to get a list of values from a list given a list of indexes; (2) how to do the same for multiple lists inside a dictionary; presumably your actual question focuses on (1), since you have shown a correct solution for (2)?

Comment: It doesn't rebuild the dictionary, it builds *another* dictionary. If you want a dictionary as result, this is what you have to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I index a list with another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list)

Comment: You can do it in-place but creating a new dictionary is fine, are you actually worried about memory consumption?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension to loop over the original list `items`, then for each sublist in values use a list comprehension to index out from your `indexes`

```
>>> {k: [v[i] for i in indexes] for k,v in a.items()}
{'x': [1, 3], 'y': [10, 30]}
```

Comment: The OP explicitly wants to avoid this approach

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the existing dictionary by using slice assignment to change the list contents:

```py
for lst in a.values():
    lst[:] = [lst[i] for i in indices]
```