# Efficient way to return elements of a list using list of indices

Tags: python

```
known_cards = self.hand[self.known_index]
```

ends up giving the error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

The input here would be something along the lines of

```
self.hand = [4,2,7,9]
self.known_index = [0,3]
known_cards = [4,9] # the 0th and 3rd index of self.hand
```

I know there would be an easy fix using loops but is there a better way around it?

Comment: `known_cards = [self.hand[x] for x in self.known_index]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I index a list with another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012185/in-python-how-do-i-index-a-list-with-another-list)

Answer (score 2):

`known_cards = [ self.hand[idx] for idx in self.known_index]`

Using list comprehensions are faster than loops, in Python

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem in your code is that you are passing in a list to search for index values in a list. This can't be done, instead you can do this

```py
known_cards = [self.hand[index] for index in self.known_index]
```

This uses list comprehension, which forms a list by looping over another list.

Alternatively, `map()` can be used. It is slower, but just letting you know

```py
known_cards = list(map(lambda x : x, self.known_index))
```

This maps every value in a list, to a function, creating a new tuple. Hence, I enclose the `map()` in a `list()` to give a list